# Is it possible to use add_image_size with get_theme_file_uri?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a ACF custom field of images connected to my custom post type. However, if no image is selected it will retrieve a default image from the media library.

To display images, if check get_field('box_image') is empty/null, default to selected image with get_theme_file_uri('/assets/images/img.jpg'); function.

All images are displayed correctly below, as I have set add_image_size of 250x180, but how can I make the default image (second) render to 250x180 as well ?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  $image = get_field('box_image');
  //$size = ['sizes']['box_bg_image'];

  if (!empty($image)) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['sizes']['box_bg_image']); ?>" />
  <?php } else { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/assets/images/img.jpg'); ?>" />
  <?php } ?>
```

functions.php:

```
add_image_size('box_bg_image', 250, 180, array('center', 'center'));
```

css:

```
.bg-image img { opacity: 0.4; width: 100%; vertical-align: top; transition: opacity 0.35s; }
```

I have tried these similar outputs, but I get errors:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/assets/images/city.jpg')['sizes']['box_bg_image']; ?>" />
<img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/assets/images/city.jpg'), $size; ?>"  />
```

I have tried scouring the net to see if its possible to set the size for get_theme_file_uri image, but I cant seem to find a solution.

Should I be using a different function to assign the size?

EDIT:

I have come up with this, although I am not 100% its the right way of doing it.:

```
<img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src(158, 'box_bg_image')[0]; ?>" />
```

I know the get_theme_file_uri() retrieves one parameter and the wp_get_attachment_image_src() can take in multiple parameters, so I would think this would be one way of selecting a default image?

If anyone has other suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `get_theme_file_uri` function. It all depends on the size of your "default/placeholder" image (i.e `img.jpg`). Try to upload your "default" image to the wordpress "Media Library", it'll generate the default wordpress images sizes as well as any custom size you defined in your `functions.php` and also it gives you a `url` to that "placeholder" with different sizes. So, you could use the size you want instead of using `get_theme_file_uri('/assets/images/img.jpg');`. The `url` would be something like this: `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/img-250x180.jpg`

Comment: Ok. However, I want to avoid hardcoding the `width=""` in the url like that. That is why I ended up using the `wp_get_attachment_image_src(158, 'box_bg_image')[0];` which gives me more parameters to work with.

Comment: You won't! Wordpress will generate the `url` by default. You then could go to  your file directory and rename it and remove the `250x180` from your file.

Comment: Ok. I am still learning. So, like this you saying: `get_theme_file_uri('https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/img-250x180.jpg');` ?

Comment: When you **upload** your default image through **media library**, it'll generate a `url`. You don't need to use `get_theme_file_uri`. That `url` is NOT located in your theme directory. It's located in your `uploads` folder. Simply use the address wordpress gives you. `'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/img-250x180.jpg'`

Comment: Okay. I gotcha, like a regular html way of adding url. Is there something wrong than with using the `wp_get_attachment_image_src(158, 'box_bg_image')[0];` option? I think using the wordpress function is better.

Comment: No there is nothing wrong with that approach, if that works, then, great. There is always multiple ways of doing the same thing. Although i'm still a little bit confused on which `image` you're talking about. Is it the "placeholder" image you're talking about or is it your custom "box_bg_image" image. If it's the placeholder one, then why are you using `box_bg_image`.

Comment: Ah right, okay, cool. box_bg_image is the custom image size. Thanks for your help  @Ruvee

Answer (score 0):

Use `object-fit` property for that purpose

Here are some and can [refer to this for more info abut `object-fit`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp) :
**contain :** The image keeps its aspect ratio, but is resized to fit within the given dimension
**cover :** The image keeps its aspect ratio and fills the given dimension. The image will be clipped to fit
**none :** The image is not resized
**scale-down :** the image is scaled down to the smallest version of none or contain

Comment: how can I render the image to 250x180 via add_image_size like I did for get_field ['sizes']['box_bg_image'] ?

Comment: Srry don't know about `php` way thought this might help as it solved my problems very well for images of different sizes and fix them certain dimensions

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
<img src="<?php echo $fetch['image]" width="200px" height="200px">
```

Comment: I did try the width="", but that is hardcoding it in. I want to make the default image get the add_image_size assigned, not by css like that.